# Link for public users to join my TEAMS.SE?

Tags: support, new-users, moderation, stack-overflow-for-teams

How do I create a link for other members the public domains of SE to click on that would allow the user to request to join my TEAMS.SE?

Comment: Do you understand that teams has a _per user_ cost, don’t you?

Comment: @yivi still learning the differences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User administration is explained in the [Teams Help Center](https://www.stackoverflow.help/support/home).

- You can [configure an email domain](https://www.stackoverflow.help/support/solutions/articles/36000061151-how-to-manage-email-domains-for-auto-joining-the-team) to allow someone to join your team based on their email address.
- You can [send out individual invites](https://www.stackoverflow.help/support/solutions/articles/36000061150-how-to-invite-users-individually).

As yivi wrote in a comment and as explained in the [Billing Policy](https://www.stackoverflow.help/support/solutions/articles/36000074939-billing-policy) article, there's a price attached to adding users:

> Teams start at $10 per month (or $120 annually) and include your first 10 users. Additional users are $6/user billed monthly or $5/user billed annually (so you pay $60 upfront for the whole year per user).

Comment: So I need to make a link that a public user can click on that asks for their email for me to send them an invite? How do I do that?

Comment: Teams does not have such a feature (I think). Are you sure that Teams is the right product for you?

Comment: I was hoping to use it as a gym to learn all the facets of the SE system without penalty.

Comment: @Muze Without an actual community, you wouldn’t learn anything useful.

Comment: @Muze You’d do better and learn faster if you focus instead on the same feedback you constantly do get on SE, and then internalized it, believed it, and acted on it. Instead of hearing it and trying to find ways around it. Which honestly is what I personally observed you to do, on several SE stacks now.

Comment: @DanBron I'm not trying to circumvent anything but trying to understand the algorithms so I may help improve on them.

Comment: @Muze It’s not algorithms. It’s people. And I’m telling you what I’ve observed, I’m not asking a question.